# Unable to apply custom Tailwind CSS theme using extend in a React component library

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, esbuild

I am currently working on a React component library that includes theming functionality. The library allows consumers to override custom theme variables and Tailwind CSS configurations.

In the library's entry point, I have the following code:

```
// entryPoint.js

import "./global.css";
import tailwindConfig from "../tailwind.config";

export function applyCustomTheme(theme: any) {
  const root = document.documentElement;
  const { customTheme, tailwindTheme } = theme;
  
  Object.entries(customTheme).forEach(([property, value]: any) => {
    root.style.setProperty(`--${property}`, value);
  });

  if (tailwindConfig.theme && tailwindTheme) {
    tailwindConfig.theme.extend = {
      ...tailwindConfig.theme.extend,
      ...tailwindTheme,
    };
    console.log(tailwindConfig); // Logging updated tailwindConfig
  }
}

export * from "./atoms";
```

I have added the feature to override custom theme variables, and I'm attempting to extend the Tailwind CSS configuration with the provided tailwindTheme. However, when I consume the library in a separate project and attempt to apply the custom theme, the Tailwind CSS configurations do not seem to be updated.

Here's how I'm consuming the library:

```
// consumer.js

import { applyCustomTheme } from "component-lib";

const theme = {
  customTheme: {
    "primary-color": "#00f",
  },
  tailwindTheme: {
    colors: {
      "white": "#f3f"
    }
  },
};

applyCustomTheme(theme);
```

Am I missing something in the way I'm extending the Tailwind CSS configurations? I expect the custom Tailwind CSS configurations to be applied globally when using the library, but it seems like the changes are not taking effect. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Main Issue:** The tailwindTheme is being inserted into tailwindConfig.theme.config but isn't being applied to the project.

Library: React component library using esbuild bundler, Tailwind CSS, React

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something in the way you are extending the Tailwind CSS configurations.

Tailwind runs in an isolated PostCSS "thread" from your application. Tailwind itself consumes the `tailwind.config.js/ts/cjs` file. The `applyCustomTheme()` function does nothing to the Tailwind configuration when Tailwind parses it, since your `consumer.js` would be in a different "thread" or "instance" to that of which Tailwind runs.

You could consider utilizing [Tailwind presets](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets) to have a Tailwind configuration packaged with the component library that could then be extended/overridden by consumers.

Comment: I am currently exporting two functions: applyCustomTheme, which updates custom CSS variables, and provides an option to override the Tailwind theme directly within this function. I am logging the Tailwind config, which includes the extend value passed through applyCustomTheme. However, it seems that the Tailwind theme is not being overridden as intended.

Comment: Indeed. Tailwind runs in an isolated PostCSS "thread" from your application. Tailwind itself consumes the `tailwind.config.js/ts/cjs` file. The `applyCustomTheme()` function does nothing to the Tailwind configuration when Tailwind parses it, since your `consumer.js` would be in a different "thread" or "instance" to that of which Tailwind runs.

Comment: Can the settings of the Tailwind component library in the consumer project be configured?

Comment: Yes, you could consider utilizing [Tailwind presets](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets) to have a Tailwind configuration packaged with the component library that could then be extended/overridden by consumers.

Comment: I have examined the presets, and while attempting to import a preset from the consumer app to the component library, I noticed that the theme remained unchanged. Could you please provide more detailed information on this matter?

Comment: Yes, see [detailed information on Tailwind presets on the Tailwind documentation website](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets).